# Oracle reports repeating frame

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oraclereports

I am creating a report with Oracle reports  10g. I used frame and repeating frame in page layout. I have only one question. My client wants the data to be on the same page. Let's say a frame's data started on the 1st page and moved to the 2nd page, then I wants all the data to move to the 2nd page. How can I achieve this in rdf?

Answer (score 0):

Set frame's "Page protect" property to "Yes":

[image]

Comment: hello littlefoot I try that before and didn't work. 
                                                    
 https://r.resimlink.com/VD6xAjQ28Z.png

Comment: It *should*. Did you set that property for all frames that enclose data that should be kept *together*?

Comment: Yes  .  https://r.resimlink.com/0rLSO1cvW23_.png                                   I have alot of frame in this rdf I set m_1 , r_1 and m_5 , r_5 because I want to change just that frame

Comment: Well, "Page protect" property does what you want. Did you try to modify vertical **elasaticity** as well?

Comment: Yes I was using as an expand  but I changed to variable